# Change li class on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here's my html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="rbx-tab">
        <a class="rbx-tab-heading" href="#limiteds" id="tab-limiteds">
            <span class="rbx-lead">Limiteds</span>
            <span class="rbx-tab-subtitle"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When someone clicks on **Limiteds**, how do I change the following:

1. Change the li class **rbx-tab** to **rbx-tab active**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many answers already, and here another option you can use :

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li class="rbx-tab"> 
    <a class="rbx-tab-heading" href="#limiteds" id="tab-limiteds">
         <span class="rbx-lead">Limiteds</span>
         <span class="rbx-tab-subtitle"></span>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li class="rbx-tab">
    <a class="rbx-tab-heading" href="#limiteds" id="tab-limiteds">
        <span class="rbx-lead">Limiteds</span>
        <span class="rbx-tab-subtitle"></span>
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

Register click event on anchor tag, after that `remove existing class definition` attached to `li` element using [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/). Lastly, add class to current context using [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
// clicking on anchor element inside li
$('li a').click(function () {
   // remove existing active class inside li elements
   $('li.rbx-tab').removeClass('active');
  // add class to current clicked element
   $(this).closest('li.rbx-tab').addClass('active');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/L478bovd/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery like,
for a single li,
1. use addClass for it.

```
$(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
```

To toggle it on every click, use,

```
$(this).parents('li').toggleClass('active');
```

for multiple li's,
1. Remove active class from all the li.
2. Add active class only to that li using $(this).

Answer (score 0):

Use `AddClass` of Jquery

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("rbx-tab active");
  alert($(this).attr("class"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="rbx-tab">
    <a class="rbx-tab-heading" href="#limiteds" id="tab-limiteds">
      <span class="rbx-lead">Limiteds</span>
      <span class="rbx-tab-subtitle"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With `toggleClass`

```js
$("li").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("active");

  alert($(this).attr("class"));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="rbx-tab">
  <a class="rbx-tab-heading" href="#limiteds" id="tab-limiteds">
    <span class="rbx-lead">Limiteds</span>
    <span class="rbx-tab-subtitle"></span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**For more info:**https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
and
https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in one line:

```
$("li a").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".rbx-tab").toggleClass("active");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qb9a83Lt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using the following code:

```
$('a .rbx-lead').click(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
```

or simpler:

```
$('a .rbx-lead').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
```

please find example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/q696xsdk/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".rbx-lead").click(function(){
  $(".rbx-tab").attr('class', ".rbx-tab active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer will be this

```
$('li a').click(function () {
    $('li.rbx-tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li.rbx-tab').addClass('active');
});
```